# Modify AWS Switch Role Display Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

AWS allows switching your roles to seamlessly access different accounts. How to modify the `Display Name` parameter once it is entered and saved (along with the `Account` and `Role` values).

[image: Screen-while-configuring-switch-role]

Comment: I think it is stored in browser cookies rather than on AWS itself. There are a number of browser plugins (eg [AWS Extend Switch Roles - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aws-extend-switch-roles/jpmkfafbacpgapdghgdpembnojdlgkdl)) that can help you manage the configuration.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no Edit page for the roles, so what you should do is to click the account drop-down at the top right and select `Switch Roles`, then re-create the role with the new display name.

The new setup will overwrite the old one.

Answer (score 17):

There is a cookie named: noflush_awsc-roleInfo. If you delete that cookie from the browser dev console entire role history will be dropped.

Comment: Or you can edit the "d" part(s) of that cookie to change the description(s)

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, the `noflush_awsc-roleInfo` cookie holds the history of your switched profiles.

The data is `url encoded json string`. When `decoded`, you get a `json` output that contains a list of `objects` that has 4 different parameters `a (account id)`,`r (role name)`,`d (display name)`,`c (color)`. Edit these to your liking, and edit/update the cookie value, to change the console history.